# Ideas to improve query performance

Tags: mysql, query-performance

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pn_posts.id 
FROM   pn_posts 
       LEFT JOIN pn_term_relationships 
              ON ( pn_posts.id = pn_term_relationships.object_id ) 
       INNER JOIN pn_postmeta 
               ON ( pn_posts.id = pn_postmeta.post_id ) 
       INNER JOIN pn_postmeta AS mt1 
               ON ( pn_posts.id = mt1.post_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN pn_wc_product_meta_lookup wc_product_meta_lookup 
              ON pn_posts.id = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id 
WHERE  1 = 1 
       AND ( pn_posts.id NOT IN (SELECT object_id 
                                 FROM   pn_term_relationships 
                                 WHERE  term_taxonomy_id IN ( 8 )) 
             AND pn_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 21 ) ) 
       AND ( pn_postmeta.meta_key = '_manage_stock' 
             AND mt1.meta_key = '_stock_status' ) 
       AND pn_posts.post_type = 'product' 
       AND ( pn_posts.post_status = 'publish' ) 
GROUP  BY pn_posts.id 
ORDER  BY pn_postmeta.meta_value ASC, 
          Field (mt1.meta_value, 'instock', '3days', 'outofstock'), 
          wc_product_meta_lookup.min_price ASC 
LIMIT  48, 24;
```

[image]

Comment: A non-ERM table structure? Is it particularly slow? Can it be cached? aka - how often does the return value change / do inaccuracies matter?

Comment: Condition other than IS NULL by right table in WHERE - and LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

A first step in improving the performance of WordPress is to change the "meta" schema as discussed here:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

If that does not help enough, I will take a deeper look at your query.